# C++ - Passing array from function to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

So I have this code:

main.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    matrix m;
    regularMatrix rMatrix;

    rMatrix.setDetails(3, "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
    //rMatrix.displayMatrix();

    //int i, j, r = 0, c = 0, a;


    //cout << "Enter number of Rows and Columns: " << endl;

    //cin >> r ;












    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"

int rows = 3, columns = 3;
int **a;




void matrix::displayMatrix(int **arr)
{

    cout  <<  "Values Of 2D Array [Matrix] Are : ";
    for  (int i  =  0;  i  <  rows;  i++  )
    {
         cout  <<  " \n ";
         for  (int j  =  0;  j  <  columns;  j++  )
         {
              cout <<  arr[i][j] << "    ";
         }
    }
}

void matrix::setDetails(int dimension, string y)
{
     int f = dimension;
     rows = dimension;
     columns = rows;
     string input = y;

     istringstream is(input);
     int n;

     a = new int *[rows];
     for(int i = 0; i <rows; i++)
     {
             a[i] = new int[columns];
     }   



     for  ( int i  =  0;  i  <  rows;  i++  )
     {
          for  ( int j  =  0;  j  <  columns;  j++  )
          {
               while ( is >> n)
               {
                     a[i][j] = n;
                     //cout << a[i][j] << endl;
               }
          }
     }



     matrix::displayMatrix(a);

     //cout << f << endl << g << endl;
}
```

---

matrix.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class matrix
{
      public:
             virtual void displayMatrix(int** arr);
             virtual void setDetails(int dimension, string y);
             //virtual void setMatrix(int m[]);
             //virtual void printArray(int** i);


};

class regularMatrix : public virtual matrix
{
      public:


};
```

It runs without error but the problem is, I'm getting different value when I'm displaying the matrix? I think I'm getting the address of the array.How will I get the value out of it? I think I'm right about passing my array.

Comment: Consider using debugger tool with watches window open and go through the code step by step. It's really good in dealing with this sort of problems

Comment: Consider also using std::vector instead of arrays. All these woes (including the memory leak you're not seeing there) will go away :).

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] that reproduces you problem please. Also add information about what you observed during debugging your code. It's likely that you output uninitialzezed values from `arr[i][j]` rather then _addresses_.

Comment: It's a project that requires array so I won't be able to use vectors this time. @TheMarlboroMan

Comment: @Zelgh Strange requirement, what makes that up actually?

Comment: you can always get a c-style array from a vector when needed, thus even if you have to pass arrays, I would always use a vector in my code (or `std::array` when appropriate)

Comment: Better, represent a matrix by a one dimensional array (3x3=9).

Comment: learning C may be a requirement to use this. Looks like an educational task

Comment: _what_ values do you get as output :)?

Comment: You showed us methods from matrix class, but where are methods from regularMatrix class? Since you call the method setDetails on a regularMatrix class object and not matrix class object.
Also: You create matrix object and never use it.

Comment: As said above, could you please post the entire thing?.

Comment: @teodron 

I'm getting 9, 5312416, 1886547779, 5318528, 5312416, 1547322171, 5318528, 5312416, 1684957527

Comment: You also have this commented out `cout` during your assignment. are the values correct there?

Comment: @Zelgh try also printing the values for the (i,j) index pairs. See if you understand what happens. And why :).

Comment: I think that while loop is the culprit. Lemme try, thanks for pointing that out. @teodron

Comment: Again, thank you all for viewing my question. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for  (  i  =  0;  i  <  rows;  i++  )
 {
      for  (  j  =  0;  j  <  columns;  j++  )
      {
           while ( is >> n)
           {
                 a[i][j] = n;
                 //cout << a[i][j] << endl;
           }
      }
 }
```

This is actually pretty wrong. Look what you're doing here. 
At beggining, you have `i = 0 and j = 0`

Then you got into the `while` loop.

And here until you input ints from stringstream you assign `a[0][0]` to new value.
See it? You never go to a[0][1] etc. Only first element will be valid and the rest will stay uninitialized, because after first execution of your `while` loop
there is no characters left in the istringstream object.

So to correct it:

```
for  (  i  =  0;  i  <  rows;  i++  )
     {
          for  (  j  =  0;  j  <  columns;  j++  )
          {
              if ( is >> n )
              a[i][j] = n;
          }
     }
```

Comment: No problem, I added a code that should be helpful if you encountered some problems, however I am pretty sure that you already solved it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I didn't think about that!